# Angular 2 execute function in subscribe

Tags: angular

I have after ngOnInit 2 vars available items and title, items is for the view, i want to "execute" the setSeoTitle() function for the  in the index.html, how can i achieve this?

```
items = [];
title = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.slug)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.items = data;
            this.title = data;
        }
    );
}

setSeoTitle(item){
    this.seoService.setTitle(item[0]['title']);
}
```

Comment: Great, why downvoting? Not a good question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.slug)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.items = data;
            this.title = data;
            this.setSeoTitle(this.items ); ///<<###< here 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: that simple, great!

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.slug)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.items = data;
            this.title = data;
            this.setSeoTitle(this.item);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.slug)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.items = data;
            this.title = data;
            this.setSeoTitle(this.items);
        }
    );
}

setSeoTitle(items){
  if (items.length) {
    this.seoService.setTitle(items[0]['title']);
  }
}
```